# Hash Destructuring

Tags: ruby, hash, splat

You can destructure an array by using the splat operator.

```
def foo(arg1, arg2, arg3)
  #...Do Stuff...
end
array = ['arg2', 'arg3']
foo('arg1', *array)
```

But is there a way to destruct a hash for option type goodness?

```
def foo(arg1, opts)
  #...Do Stuff with an opts hash...
end
opts = {hash2: 'bar', hash3: 'baz'}
foo('arg1', hash1: 'foo', *opts)
```

If not native ruby, has Rails added something like this?

Currently I'm doing roughly this with

```
foo('arg1', opts.merge(hash1: 'foo'))
```

Comment: If you are talking about default option, yes `merge` is the way to go.

Comment: Is there any reason that you reversed the order instead of doing `{hash1: 'foo'}.merge(opts)`?

Comment: @sawa Not really. Just what came out naturally.

Answer (score 6):

It's 2018 and this deserves an update. [Ruby 2.0 introduced keyword arguments](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2013/02/24/ruby-2-0-0-p0-is-released/) and with that also the hash splat operator [`**`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/doc/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html#label-Hash+to+Keyword+Arguments+Conversion). Now you can simply do the following:

```
def foo(arg1, opts)
  [arg1, opts]
end

opts = {hash2: 'bar', hash3: 'baz'}
foo('arg1', hash1: 'foo', **opts)
#=> ["arg1", {:hash1=>"foo", :hash2=>"bar", :hash3=>"baz"}]
```

Comment: Keep in mind that this only works with symbol keys. `{**{a: 1}, **{b: 2}} #=> {:a=>1, :b=>2}` while `{**{'a' => 1}, **{'b' => 2}} #=> TypeError (wrong argument type String (expected Symbol))`

Comment: Yep. I was looking to add some keys to a `model.as_json` call and used Rails' `symbolize_keys` method: `hash = {a: 1, b: 2, **model.as_json.symbolize_keys}`

Answer (score 5):

Yes, there is a way to de-structure a hash:

```
def f *args; args; end
opts = {hash2: 'bar', hash3: 'baz'}
f *opts  #=> [[:hash2, "bar"], [:hash3, "baz"]]
```

The problem is that you what you want is actually *not* de-structuring at all. You’re trying to go from

```
'arg1', { hash2: 'bar', hash3: 'baz' }, { hash1: 'foo' }
```

(remember that `'arg1', foo: 'bar'` is just shorthand for `'arg1', { foo: 'bar' }`) to

```
'arg1', { hash1: 'foo', hash2: 'bar', hash3: 'baz' }
```

which is, by definition, merging (note how the surrounding structure—the hash—is still there). Whereas de-structuring goes from

```
'arg1', [1, 2, 3]
```

to

```
'arg1', 1, 2, 3
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no such thing (although it has been proposed). Since this will change the parsing rule, it cannot be implemented within Ruby. The best I can think of is to define `*` on hash like

```
class Hash; alias :* :merge end
```

and use it in one of the following ways:

```
foo('arg1', {hash1: 'foo'}*opts)
foo('arg1', {hash1: 'foo'} *opts)
foo('arg1', {hash1: 'foo'}. *opts)
```

the last of which I think is reasonably close to what you wanted.

Comment: Perhaps using `+` instead of `*` would make more sense?

Comment: @AndrewMarshall I agree with that. I wanted to make it look close to the splat operator.

Comment: It's now possible in Ruby 3, though with a different/new syntax: `{a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4} => {a:, b:, **rest}` (see https://www.ruby3.dev/ruby-3-fundamentals/2021/01/06/everything-you-need-to-know-about-destructuring-in-ruby-3/)

Answer (score 1):

If you're ok with using active_support:

```
require 'active_support/core_ext/hash/slice.rb'

def foo(*args)
  puts "ARGS: #{args}"
end

opts = {hash2: 'bar', hash3: 'baz'}
foo *opts.slice(:hash2, :hash3).values
```

...or you could monkey-patch your own solution:

```
class Hash
  def pluck(*keys)
    keys.map {|k| self[k] }
  end
end

def foo(*args)
  puts "ARGS: #{args}"
end

opts = {hash2: 'bar', hash3: 'baz'}
foo *opts.pluck(:hash2, :hash3)
```